# Merging two models in Keras Functional API

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am messing around with wide and deep models and trying to implement something basic with keras. I am able to produce a simple model and a deep nn using the functional keras. However, I'm having some issues ensembling the two.

```
###############################################################################
###############################################################################

inputs = Input(shape = (X_train.shape[1],))
output = Dense(1, activation='linear')(inputs)
wide = Model(inputs, output)

wide.compile(
        optimizer = 'adam',
        loss = 'mean_squared_error',
        metrics = ['accuracy']
)

wide.fit(x = X_train, y = Y_train, epochs = 10, verbose = 1)

###############################################################################
###############################################################################

inputs = Input(shape = (X_train.shape[1],))
x = Dense(200, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', 
               activation = 'relu')(inputs)
x = Dense(100, activation = 'relu')(x)
x = Dense(50, activation = 'relu')(x)
output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
deep = Model(inputs, output)

deep.compile(
        optimizer = 'adam',
        loss = 'mean_squared_error',
        metrics = ['accuracy']
)

deep.fit(x = X_train, y = Y_train, epochs = 10, verbose = 1)

###############################################################################
###############################################################################

merge = Concatenate([wide, deep])
    hidden1 = Dense(10, activation='relu')(merge)
    output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(hidden1)
    model = Model(inputs=visible, outputs=output)
```

How can I go about concatenating the two models?

I get this error:

```
ValueError: Layer dense_36 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor. Received type: <class 'keras.layers.merge.Concatenate'>. Full input: [<keras.layers.merge.Concatenate object at 0x1a1adda588>]. All inputs to the layer should be tensors.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Concatenate` layer works exactly as the others.

- Layer parameters in the first parentheses (layer creation)
- Input tensors in the second parentheses (calling the layer to get outputs)
- Inputs must be tensors, not models

So:

```
merge = Concatenate()([wide.outputs,deep.outputs])
```

A merged model must start from the very first two inputs:

```
model = Model(inputs=[wide.inputs,deep.inputs], outputs=output)
```

Comment: It would more true to the API if the models were called like layers to get the corresponding outputs `wide(inputs)` rather than `.outputs`

Comment: Not sure if "more true", but it's a common standard method indeed, but that creates more nodes and may need extra attention later if you're going to derive more models, try custom functions, etc. /// On the other hand, if you want to have two models in series and yet having the option to use them separately, you suggestion is the way to go.

Comment: @DanielMöller, I have two separate models, both have 2 classes. Now I want to merge them and create a single model which will have 1 input layer + 4 classes in the end. is it possible? if yes, then do we need to train it again?

Answer (score 0):

keras 2.1 and higher:

```
merge = Concatenate()([wide.output,deep.output])
model = Model(inputs=[wide.input,deep.input], outputs=output)
```

because, `.outputs` and `.input`  return the list, not tensor